# How to implement a pluck function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I often need to pluck properties out of an object

```
const obj = {a:1, b: 2, c: 3};
const plucked = pluck(obj, 'a', 'b'); // {a: 1, b:2}
```

However, this is not easy to do in TypeScript if you want type safety because I can't implement a function with the following signature in TypeScript, which I found on [TypeScript's manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick).

```
declare function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K>;
```

I couldn't get a version that compiled, here's a version I tried:

```
function pluck<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
    // Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Pick<T, K>'.
    const ret: Pick<T, K> = {};
    for (let key of keys) { 
        ret[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return ret; 
}
```

Does this mean I need to use ambient declarations and declare the function in JS?

Comment: Yes there is no way to express in TypeScript type system that you are taking an empty object and modify it in a way that it becomes compatible with some type. The usual workaround is to use type assertion like `const ret = {} as Pick<T, K>;`

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using `any` on the object that I manipulate and TypeScript is happy allowing that as a return value. [See it in action](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20pluck%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20keys%3A%20K%5B%5D)%3A%20Pick%3CT%2C%20K%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20ret%3A%20any%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20key%20of%20keys)%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ret%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20obj%5Bkey%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20ret%3B%20%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20less%20%3D%20pluck(%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%20'2'%2C%20c%3A%20true%20%7D%2C%20%5B'a'%2C%20'c'%5D)%3B%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A)

```
function pluck<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
    const ret: any = {};
    for (let key of keys) { 
        ret[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return ret; 
}

const less = pluck({ a: 1, b: '2', c: true }, ['a', 'c']);
```

Comment: yes, don't take the type too seriously within your code boundary. It is a tool to help you work more efficiently. If you have sufficient tests to cover the use cases, it is fine to use `any`. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative option:

```
function pluck<T, K extends keyof T>(objs: T, keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  return keys.reduce((result, key) => 
    Object.assign(result, {[key as string]: objs[key]}), {}) as Pick<T, K>;
}
```