# How to improve the Type of this 'pluck' util function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, typeorm

This is the util:

```
export const pluck = (obj: any = {}, keys: string[] = []) =>
  keys.reduce((acc: any, curr: any) => ({ ...acc, [curr]: obj[curr] }), {});
```

And I'd use it like this:

```
const data: FollowerType = pluck(req.body, [
    'createdById',
    'createdForId',
    'isHidden',
    'isMutual',
  ]);
```

Instead of doing this:

```
const { createdById, createdForId, isHidden, isMutual } = req.body;
const data: FollowerType = { createdById, createdForId, isHidden, isMutual };
```

But my util isn't producing the most informative error messages for types when I use it. Is there a better way to write the util function?

Comment: I believe this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341226/how-to-implement-a-pluck-function-in-typescript That's typically called `pluck` The answer is that there is no magic way to be 100% safe but you can at least keep the callers safe. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't provide the answer I'm looking for, I implemented pluck and get the same result. Do you mind re-opening?

IE I didnt get an error when using the wrong key

Comment: [Here's your code using that](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=27&ssc=4&pln=23&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwDYggawDwBUA0iA0ogKYAeUpYAJgM6KakCecwiuAfABRwBGAKwBcHQk2Z0RRANoBdAJQiACjCx5CRTogDeAKEQHEqUlEQAnEyICGYZogC8OgL4BufYeBwzibsdPjENkYWOnkdRHdDQwsoaXFZB0DBOJZZNyinSPMTEDMkGJcIzJgwKjNgKwhSRAAxOFRUOAB3UjNcZmRqvSiICysqGgAhZgBJGhEwEABbPlb0w17SftIaOrMxienZs3mDGDoACRgaGmoRPjh6pbBdxH2AWRAoECtUc8vjGzdMiAQ6UwsAEdEt1DBcaMwRKCogZFsshqNxogACwAJnwWR6fQGaw2iAAjPiAOwYmGGfZHE5nRAVVB0Uiksl3OiPZ6vES0+lZTKuXS-MD-RA0fpWER1BrNVrtTqJNAYTDcIEAOnBzEI0l0AHI4QNhmNNRjtdiVriaAatRTjqcwObNQ8ni9UOaFC4gA)

Comment: stephano - What specifically is it that's wrong? @Juan's `pluck` seems to work perfectly for this use case, see my link above.

Comment: [Better](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwDYggawDwBUA0iA0ogKYAeUpYAJgM6KakCecwiuAfABRwBGAKwBcHQk2Z0RRANoBdAJQiACjCx5CRTogDeAKEQHEqUlEQAnEyICGYZogC8OgL4BufYeBwzibsdPjENkYWOnkdRHdDQwsoaXFZB0DBOJZZNyinSPMTEDMkGJcIzJgwKjNgKwhSRAAxOFRUOAB3UjNcZmRqvSiICysqGgAhZgBJGhEwEABbPlb0w17SftIaOrMxienZs3mDGDoACRgaGmoRPjh6pbBdxH2AWRAoECtUc8vjGzdMiAQ6UwsAEdEt1DBcaMwRKCogZFsshqNxogACwAJnwWR6fQGaw2iAAjPiAOwYmGGfZHE5nRAVVB0Uiksl3OiPZ6vES0+mMsngCyoeEiABEnjggu5MLocCmJgAFiUAOYAUTppCFfCsZkFWUyrl0vzA-0QNH6VhEdQazVa7U6iTQGEw3CBADpwcxCNJdAByOEDYZjT0Y73Yla4mgBr0U46nMDhz0PJ4vVDhhQuIA).

Comment: ^^ better example of applying @Juan's `pluck` to your case above.

Comment: @stephano I don't understand why it doesn't answer your question. Please explain it further, I'll vote to reopen if it makes sense

Comment: As will I if @Juan's not around.

Comment: My Bad! It worked. Thank you!.

I have an additional set of functions that have the same problems: 

`export const omitKeys = (obj: any = {}, arr: string[] = []) =>
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc: any, curr: string) => {
    if (arr.includes(curr)) {
      return acc;
    }
    return { ...acc, [curr]: obj[curr] };
  }, {});`

And

Comment: `Meaning I'd have to change things in 2 places every time I change a key` To avoid this, create a helper function that calls your pluck with the required keys, if things change, you can just change that one function.

Comment: `export const removeFalsyKeys = (obj: object = {}): object =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc: object, curr: any[]) => {
    if (curr[1]) {
      return { ...acc, [curr[0]]: curr[1] };
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});`

Comment: @JuanMendes It absolutely does, it worked, I apologise! :)

Comment: @stephano Did you look at the typescript reference link I posted? You probably want to use [Exclude<T,U>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu) If you can't get it to work, please post a new question

Comment: @JuanMendes Okay, Ill give it a try

Comment: @JuanMendes hey so pluck doesn't tell me when I'm using a key that doesn't exist on the type. eg if type doesn't have field 'foo' and I pluck 'foo' it doesn't err

Comment: @stephano If you need that kind of behavior, you need to throw an exception if the object property doesn't exist in the source objects. As I said, this is not 100% type safe. However, throwing an error is not necessarily the only approach, your returned object does have the property but it's set to `undefined`. We like focused questions and avoid refining questions in comments, please ask a new question if you would like so it can be helpful to others.

Comment: A safer approach is to return `Partial<Pick<T,K>>` and compile with `--strictNullChecks` which would force callers to check that properties are defined. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13783#issuecomment-276424019

Comment: @JuanMendes Perfect! That worked.
Also here is my omit function, is this correct? I noticed there was an Exclude util type AND an Omit util type, why use Exclude for omit func rather than Omit?

`export const omit = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]): Partial<Exclude<T, K>> => {
  const ret: any = {};
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (!obj[key]) {
      ret[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return ret;
};
`

Comment: Ill post a question as soon as my 90 minutes are up!

Comment: @JuanMendes made Q here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60951185/im-converting-my-util-functions-to-more-type-safe-variants-and-having-trouble