# How to have a Type-Safe 'omit' util function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

Currently I have this function, the typing is not correct, how can I change this to receive better type information?

```
export const omit = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]): Partial<Exclude<T, K>> => {
  const ret: any = {};
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (!obj[key]) {
      ret[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return ret;
};
```

EDIT: An answer to this question was posted here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60971529/edit

Comment: You should focus on one of them, I would keep the top one and delete the others (or ask separate questions if they are not all the same root cause). We like focused questions so they can be more helpful to others and easy to search for. Also, please add further details explaining what the problem is. Show input/output, actual vs. expected behavior.

Comment: @JuanMendes Made requested changes to the question

Comment: What's not type safe about this? Sorry to keep bugging you but you are not explaining actual vs expected behavior? Show a broken use case

Comment: @JuanMendes https://pastebin.com/zg0nDD5R
Same goes for omit

Comment: A link to an external site is fine but you still need to show the code here. Actual vs expected behavior is the best way to explain. Your linked code is for a pluck and not omit. Please stay focused on one issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I'm really trying to help you ask better questions so that more people will want to help you

Comment: @JuanMendes I understand, thank you for helping. I'll try to ask more focused questions based on actual vs expected.