# Pass keys from type to object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is probably a very trivial question, but after reading other answers on typescript, my head is exploding.

Lets say I have a type of User fields I want to get

```
export type UserFileds = {
  id: User["id"];
  email: User["email"];
  emailVerified: User["emailVerified"];
  image: User["image"];
  name: User["name"];
};
```

Now I need to get all of those fileds from the data I get. This is how I make it before:

```
const { id, email, emailVerified, image, name } = user as User;
return  { id, email, emailVerified, image, name };
```

How can I put dynamically all this keys from UserFileds, like:

```
const { "list of keys of UserFileds" } = user as User;
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you consider using Object.keys(obj), but that would return you an array? Would that work for you?

Comment: What is `User`? Please consider providing a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE like [the TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WPZMEN).  The TypeScript type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) from the emitted JavaScript, so there's no `UserFields` at runtime to do anything with.  Seems like you will need to create a list of these keys at runtime no matter what; there's no shortcut to do it for you.  Personally I'd write something like a `pluck()` function as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49341226/2887218).

Comment: ...but without a minimal reproducible example this is mostly just conjecture.